# Convergence about a conditional double random array

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability, law-of-large-numbers

Suppose we have i.i.d. random variables $\{X_1, X_2, \cdots\}$. And for each $X_i$, we have i.i.d. random variables $\{Y_{i, 1}, Y_{i, 2}, \cdots\}$ that are conditioned on $X_i$. Generally, $P(Y|X_i)\neq P(Y|X_k)$ if $i\neq k$. Additionally, we assume $Y_{i,j}$ are bounded or even binary.

Now we have a double array $\{Y_{i,j}:i\geq 1,j\geq 1\}$.
For each $i$, we define
$$S_{i,n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n Y_{i,j}.$$
By the strong law of large numbers, we have
$$S_{i,n}\to E[Y|X_i] \ \ \ a.s.\    \ \ n\to \infty.$$

***My question*** is about the convergence of the mean of the double array:
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n S_{i,n} \overset{?}{\to} \mu = E[Y] = E[E[Y|X]],    \ \ n\to \infty.$$

If regard $Z_i=E[Y|X_i]$ as a random variable, we have
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i \overset{}{\to} \mu \ \ a.s.    \ \ n\to \infty.$$
However, I found it may be incorrect to derive directly
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n S_{i,n}\to\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i\to \mu \ \ \ a.s.\ \  n\to \infty.$$

Comment: what is $P(Y|X_i)$? I think you meant $\mathbb{E}(Y|X_i)$. But if it is the case, you must have $\mathbb{E}(Y|X_i) = \mathbb{E}(Y|X_k)$ and so $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n S_{i,n} \to \mu = E[Y] = E[E[Y|X]],    \ \ n\to \infty.$$

Comment: Emmm, I mean that $P(Y|X_i)$ is a probability that is determined by $X_i$ and it is not $\mathbb{E}[Y|X_i]$.

Comment: $P(Y|X_i)$ makes no sense. You need a statement, for exemple $P(Y>0|X_i)$ for the probability.